# How to automatically clean up users not logged in since 90days in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

My requirements are to find all the users not logged in via Azure AD since last 45 days and last 90days and take action. That is,

1. A daily nightly job to run on Azure AD and if it finds users not login since last 45days; it should automatically disable the users.
2. A daily nightly job to run on Azure AD and if it finds users not login since last 90days or previous inactive users; it should delete the users.

[This](https://azvise.com/2021/11/08/automatically-clean-up-guest-users-in-azure-ad/) link looks similar where it’s going via a review process. However, my requirements are bit simple.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for identifying and removing stale/inactive users:

1. The access review feature you linked for identifying and removing inactive users is the most seamless, built-in way to achieve this at the moment. You can specify the "days inactive" and then remove the accounts either after the review period passes or after no reviewer has responded. To [create access reviews and identify inactive users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/create-access-review), you do need to have a Premium P2 license.
2. Alternatively though, you could use an Azure Automation account or Azure Logic app to achieve the same thing. For instance, you could create an Azure Automation Powershell runbook with a daily schedule that checks the Azure AD sign-in logs and deletes the accounts based on the condition of whether they have recently signed in (i.e. where `max_TimeGenerated <= ago(45d)`). There is an [example blog post here](https://2bcloud.io/inactive-users-in-azure-active-directory/) that implements this logic. Note that to update the accountEnabled property of admin users, you need to use delegate permissions which need to run in the context of a user.
3. Another option is to query based on the lastSignInDateTime property.
   The documentation for [How To Manage Inactive Users](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-manage-inactive-user-accounts) has an example of how to query users who haven't signed in after a certain date using Microsoft Graph API.

Example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2019-06-01T00:00:00Z
```

To test the call, you can Sign in to Graph Explorer using the Global Administrator account of your tenant and execute the GET call.

Permissions Required:

1. Directory.AccessAsUser.All
2. Directory.Read.All

The SignInActivity property/endpoint is documented in detail here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-3--list-users-including-their-last-sign-in-time

If you don't want the full list of users, you can also search for a specific user by name and evaluate the lastSignInDateTime:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'marileet')&$select=displayName,signInActivity
```